# Decrease depending on increase

Tags: limits, functions

I am struggling a bit with this.

I have a slider (A) going from 0 -> 540
I also have another slider (B) going from 0.85 -> 0

Now, when I move slider A from 0 towards 540 I want slider B decreasing towards 0, so when I have reached 540 in slider A, slider B should be 0

I am not sure how to do this, how do i set up a function or formular for this?

Hope this gives meaning and am hoping for help :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should explain better what the question is.

Comment: Maybe 
$$
B = 0.85 \left(1- \frac{A}{540} \right) 
$$

Comment: @MattiP. Oh yes... Works like a charm :-) Thanks.

Comment: For next time, I recommend you to understand that this is a linear relation, and you can calculate the expression when you know the two points you want it to pass through. Have a nice day :)